# Problema de impressão com C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, array

Bom dia. Estou com um problema pra solucionar um quesito de uma questão aqui da faculdade. Segue a questão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O professor deu o código fonte (a seguir)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define dimencao 10

typedef struct celula{
    int *endereco;
    int cont;
    int tam;
}Celula;

void menu();
void  verifica(int *espaco);
void liberarEspaco(Celula vetor[]);
void inicializa(Celula vetor[]);
void cria_vetor(Celula vetor[], int posicao);
void insere(Celula vetor[]);
void imprime(Celula vetor[]);
void imprimirIntercalado(Celula vetor[]);
int maiorTam(Celula vetor[]);

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    Celula vetor[dimencao];
    int opcao;
    inicializa(vetor); // Inicializa todo o vetor com valor NULL
    menu();
    scanf("\n%d", &opcao);
    while(opcao != 0){
        system("PAUSE");
        system("cls");
            switch(opcao){
                case 1: insere(vetor); break;
                case 2: liberarEspaco(vetor); break;
                case 3: imprime(vetor); break;
                case 4: imprimirIntercalado(vetor);
                default: printf("\nValor inválido!\n"); break;
            }
        menu();
        scanf("\n%d", &opcao);
    }
    return 0;
}


void menu(){
    printf("********************* MENU *************************");
    printf("\n*\tDigite uma das opções abaixo:              *");
    printf("\n*\tDigite 1 para inserir elementos no vetor.  *");
    printf("\n*\tDigite 2 para liberação de espaço no vetor.*");
    printf("\n*\tDigite 3 para imprimir todo o vetor.       *");
    printf("\n*\tDigite 4 Imprimir intercalado inicial     *");
    printf("\n*\tDigite 0 para SAIR.                        *");
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Digite AQUI -> ");
}

void liberarEspaco(Celula vetor[]){
    int espaco;
    printf("Informe o vetor que deseja liberar: Faixa entre 1 - 10:");
    printf(" -> ");
    scanf("\n%d", &espaco);
    verifica(&espaco);
    if (vetor[espaco].endereco == NULL){
        printf("\nVetor %d VAZIO não é possível liberar espaço !!!\n\n", espaco);
    } else{
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < vetor[espaco-1].tam; i++)
            free (vetor[espaco-1].endereco[i]);
    }
}

void inicializa(Celula vetor[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<dimencao; i++){
        vetor[i].endereco = NULL;
    }
}

void cria_vetor(Celula vetor[], int posicao){

    int size;
    printf("\nInforme o tamanho do vetor na posição %d: ", posicao);
    scanf("\n%d",&size);
    while(size <= 0){
        printf("\nTamanho deve ser maior que zero !!! ");  // validar a faixa
        printf("\nInforme novamente -> ");
        scanf("\n%d",&size);
    }
    vetor[posicao-1].endereco = (int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    vetor[posicao-1].cont = 0;
    vetor[posicao-1].tam = size;
}

void insere(Celula vetor[]){

    int posicao, num;
    printf("\nQual posição você deseja inserir? Faixa entre 1 - 10: ");  // validar a faixa
    printf("-> ");
    scanf("\n%d",&posicao);
    verifica(&posicao);
    if(vetor[posicao-1].endereco == NULL){
        cria_vetor(vetor, posicao);
    }
    if(vetor[posicao-1].cont == vetor[posicao-1].tam)    //verificar se o vetor endereço está cheio
        printf("\nVetor %d está CHEIO !!! \n\n", posicao);
    else{
        printf("\nInforme o elemento: ");
        printf("-> ");
        scanf("\n%d",&num);
        vetor[posicao-1].endereco[vetor[posicao-1].cont] = num;
        vetor[posicao-1].cont++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void imprime(Celula vetor[]){

    int i, j;
     for(i=0; i<dimencao; i++){
        if (vetor[i].endereco != NULL){
            printf("\n------------");
            printf("\nVetor %d", i+1);
            printf("\n____________");
            for(j=0; j<vetor[i].cont; j++)
                printf("\n%d", vetor[i].endereco[j]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }else
          printf("\nVetor %d VAZIO", i+1);
     }
     printf("\n\n");
}

void verifica(int *espaco){
    while(*espaco < 1 || *espaco > 10){
        printf("\nPosição do vetor não corresponde! Faixa entre 1 - 10: ");  // validar a faixa
        printf("\nInforme novamente -> ");
        scanf("\n%d", &(*espaco));
    }
}

int maiorTam(Celula vetor[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int maior = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < dimencao; i++)
        if(vetor[i].tam > maior)
            maior = vetor[i].tam;

    return maior;
}

void imprimirIntercalado(Celula vetor[]) {
    int maior = maiorTam(vetor);
    int i, ic = 0, j;

    for(i = 0; i < maior; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < dimencao; j++)
            if(vetor[j].endereco[0] != NULL)
                if(vetor[j].endereco[ic] != NULL)
                    printf("%d ", vetor[j].endereco[ic]);
        ic++;
    }

}
```

Todas as vezes que tento executar a opção 4 o programa trava.

Se puderem me dar essa força, agradeço. :)

Comment: Opção 4 = void imprimirIntercalado(Celula vetor[]);

Comment: Consegue ser mais específico no que deseja? Qual o problema?

Comment: Bigown, o que está acontecendo é que eu preencho os valores e na hora que peço pra imprimir intercalado trava. Tipo, fiz o teste de imprimir todo vetor (opção 3), mostra o valor preenchido, mas na hora do intercalado... 

Eu tentei verificar se o vetor de Celula está NULL antes da leitura, mas o CodeBlocks não permitiu, dizendo que eu estava comparando um ponteiro com inteiro.

Comment: Não estará a comparar o endereço para que o pontriro aponta em vez do valor que armazena? Não vi o codigo. Já agora tente utilizar o debug step by step, passo a pasdo, do code blocks. Assim poderá saber qual a linha problemática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta tentar compilar para achar os erros sem esforço, resolvendo o ponto b:

```
free (vetor[espaco-1].endereco[i]);
```

Isto está tentando liberar um inteiro como se fosse um endereço. Provavelmente o correto seria remover o sufixo de vetor [i].

```
if(vetor[j].endereco[0] != NULL)
```

Outro caso em que um inteiro está sendo encarado como endereço, provavelmente o [0] está sobrando.

```
if(vetor[j].endereco[ic] != NULL)
```

Mais um caso, provavelmente [ic] está sobrando também, porque NULL é do tipo ponteiro, então a intenção devia ser comparar com ponteiro.

Cada um destes erros pode causar a quebra do programa. No caso específico da pergunta, é o segundo problema que causa a quebra, porque se vetor[j].endereco é um endereço nulo ou inválido, tentar ler o conteúdo deste endereço com vetor[j].endereco[n] provoca a quebra.

Comment: Ajudou bastante. Grato.